# Is it true that $\gamma\subset\overline{\Omega}$ implies $\operatorname{int}(\gamma)\subset\Omega$?

Tags: general-topology

A simply connected domain $\Omega$ in a plane has following property that if A Jordan curve $\gamma$ lies in $\Omega$ ($\gamma\subset\Omega$) then the interior of $\gamma$ is contained in $\Omega$ ($\operatorname{int}(\gamma)\subset\Omega$).

Now I do some extension to the proposition above, that if $\gamma\subset\overline{\Omega}$ then $\operatorname{int}(\gamma)\subset\Omega$, which means $\gamma $ can touch the boundary of $\Omega$. Is it true or false? I think it should be false, otherwise it would be an important property published in every textbook but actually not. Unfortunately, I cannot find a counter example.

Thanks for your precious answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.

Consider $\Omega$ whose complement is the union of the closed unit disc and the positive real axis.

Then $\overline{\Omega} = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z : |z| < 1\}$, so in particular, the unit circle itself lies within $\overline{\Omega}$ but the interior$^1$ of the unit circle, the unit disc, is even *disjoint* from $\overline{\Omega}$, hence also disjoint from $\Omega$.

---

$^1$This interior is of course not the topological interior of the unit circle as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ but rather the interior of the unit circle when viewed as a Jordan curve.  I.e. it's the unique bounded component of the complement of the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks very much. One more thing, is it true if $\Omega$ is bounded?

Comment: @zyynankai No.  I didn't use the fact that $\Omega$ is unbounded here.  Just intersect my $\Omega$ with $\{z : |z| < 2\}$ to find a bounded counterexample.

Comment: You are right! Thanks again!